# Cancelled stamp on passport

Tags: visas, cancellations, passport-stamps

I have a friend, from Zimbabwe, that stated, some time back she wanted to visit SA and got the stamp in her passport, she then, however, decided not to travel anymore. They cancelled the stamp. Can that cause any problems when applying for a visa to go to the UK?

Comment: Did she actually go back to get the visa cancelled and marked as such in her passport? Or was the visa cancelled when entering, staying or exiting SA? You should probably include a photo of the stamp (with any personal information blacked out).

Answer (score 2):

UK visa applications require you to disclose

- visa refusals to any country in the last 10 years
- removal or deportation from any country in the last 10 years
- entry refusals *to the UK* in the last 10 years

Some countries (e.g. Schengen countries) make a difference between “cancellation” and “annulment” (for both entry stamps and visas). A cancellation is serious and suggests a refusal of entry, some sort of alert or fraudulently obtained visa. An annulment is a technical measure used if a document was stamped by mistake or a visa needs to be corrected. I don't know if South Africa makes a similar distinction and whether UK immigration officers are necessarily familiar with these nuances but it can generally be inferred from the stamp itself.

If by “cancelled stamp”, she means that she has been refused entry or that the consulate reversed their decision then it should be disclosed and could obviously be a bigger issue than if the stamp has merely been annulled after she reported her change of plans to the consulate herself.